# Рекурсивный доступ ко всем значеним объекта и из замена

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста выйти из ситуации.

Есть два объекта:

- Первый:

```
payload = {
    "token": "{{token}}",
    "users": {
        "list": [
            {
                "user": "{{login}}",
                "auth": "login"
            }
        ]
    },
    "system": {
        "list": [
            {
                "id": "{{systemId}} and {{login}}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- Второй:

```
requestData = {
    "data": {
        "login": "user1",
        "token": "12345",
        "systemId": "systemId1"
    }
}
```

- Нужно:

  1. Найти все значения в payload, которые заключены в "{{}}" (Может быть несколько в одной строке).

  2. Заменить их на соответствующие значения из requestData (Например, при нахождении значения {{login}} в payload, необходимо заменить "{{login}}" на "user1" (Значение из requestData.data.login)).
- Пример объекта payload, который нужно получить в итоге:

```
payload = {
    "token": "12345",
    "users": {
        "list": [
            {
                "user": "user1",
                "auth": "login"
            }
        ]
    },
    "system": {
        "list": [
            {
                "id": "systemId1 and user1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- Что пытался сделать:

  После долгих часов пришел к рекурсии для "раскрытия" объекта, но как заменить параметры придумать не удалось.

  Рекурсия:

```
function getValue(object) {
    msg.path = object;
    console.log(msg.path)
    getProperty(object);
         
    function getProperty(key) {
        for(var value in key) {
            if(typeof(key[value]) === 'object') {
                getProperty(key[value]);
            } else {
                var keyValue = key[value];
                  //По идее тут можно было бы изменить, но как это сделать...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите, это нужно было ?

```
   payload = JSON.parse(
       JSON.stringify(payload).replace(/\{{2}(\w+)\}{2}/ig, (a,b) => requestData.data[b])
    );
    
    console.log(payload);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Простое и красивое решение. Кажется я намудрил )

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи можно использовать регулярные выражения.

Вот необходимое тебе регулярное выражение: `/\{{2}(\w+)\}{2}/gi`

Чтобы получить строковое значение внутри, используй `RegExp.prototype.exec()[1]`. Более подробно можно узнать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression).

Данный метод возвращает первый попавшийся результат разбитый по группам. Регулярка выше построена так, что первой группой будет как раз все строковое значение (без скобок). Далее, заменить их на значения из другого объекта я думаю будет не сложно.